# Get status of blob_copy method used with Azure?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a python code that requests a blob copy in Azure, and I want to check if the copy was done successfully. How can I retrieve this status?

Here is an example of my code:

```
uri = myuri
ret = blob_service.copy_blob(BLOB_CONTAINER, Destiny, Source)
```

In `ret` I have the id of the copy service and the initial status. How can I get the status of this now? I want to check if the copy was finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is fetch the properties of blob. Properties returned will include copy operation related properties.

The method you’ll call is `get_blob_properties`. You can see more details about this method here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py.